# How to implement a gRPC server in c++ that using asynchronously handles multiple RPC?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, protocol-buffers, grpc

I need to implement a gRPC server in C++ that can handle multiple RPC asynchronously .

This is the sample proto I want to use,

```
syntax = "proto3";
package test;

service test{
    rpc Modify(stream ModifyRequest) returns (stream ModifyResponse);
    rpc Get(GetRequest) returns (stream GetResponse);
}

message GetRequest {
    string GetRequestMessage=1;
}

message GetResponse {
    string GetResponseMessage=1;
}

message ModifyRequest {
    string ModifyRequestMessage=1;
}

message ModifyResponse {
    string ModifyResponseMessage=1;
}
```

How can we use completion queue and achieve this. In the example provided in gRPC official page its only available for the server streaming scenario. Can someone explain or share references on how this can be achieved in C++?

I tried reading reading this reference https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc

But it is only for server streaming scenario, I need to know how it can be done for bi directional streaming too.